Why this function can accept the class type when it's not compatible with the method parameter type
Why func(x2) is valid? When x2.index require F2 to be passed into it but func only pass F1
class F1 {
    value: string = ''
}

class F2 extends F1 {
    value2: number = 0
}

abstract class X1 {
    abstract index(param: F1): void
}

class X2 extends X1 {
    override index(param: F2): void {
        // Here [param] must be [F2]
        console.log(`Is F2: ${param instanceof F2}`)
    }
}


const func = (x: X1) => {
    const f1 = new F1()

    x.index(f1)
}

const x2 = new X2()

// Why [X2] can be passed here? No error?
// [X2.index] [param] should only accept [F2]
// But [func] will pass [F1] into it.
func(x2)

// The expected is that [func] should not be able to accept [X2].
func(x2) // Error expected

Playground

Because X2.index require F2 but it got F1. so param.value2 will be undefined when it should not.

Despite seeming counter-intuitive, this is valid TypeScript code. The problem with it is that class X2 violates the Liskov substitution principle, which in short states that:

...an object (such as a class) may be replaced by a sub-object (such as a class that extends the first class) without breaking the program.

Specifically in this case, what breaks the aforementioned principle is the fact that X2 overrides X1.index(param: F1) (OK to do) while changing its parameter to expect a derived type of F1, which is F2 (becoming "not ok") and then accesses a field that exists only in that derived type (<- breaks the principle).
You can update your types and func like below so that it throws an error if LSP is violated.
abstract class X1<TIndex extends F1> {
    abstract index(param: TIndex): void;
}

class X2 extends X1<F2> {
    override index(param: F2): void {
        // Here [param] must be [F2]
        console.log(`Is F2: ${param instanceof F2}`)        
    }
}


const func = <TIndex extends F1>(x: X1<TIndex>) => {
    const f1 = new F1()

    x.index(f1) // <-- throws error
}

Link to full code can be found in this playground.
(edit: inspiration taken from Sander van 't Einde's answer)

There is no solution to this problem? or is this a ts bug? But if changing the F1 -> F2 is not ok why typescript doesn't make any error?

This is not a bug, it's just bad practice.

To ensure you respect this principle (and not break your program), you can implement a typecheck similar to the one described by Sander van 't Einde https://stackoverflow.com/a/78453709/13775124

See my comment in his answer, it doesn't make error either

I updated my original answer with a link to TS playground with the updated code that respects LSP while throwing an error if it's violated.

I think it might be I'm just using a bad practice or there is other way, I'm using this for a http library like there is BaseMiddleware and ExpressMiddleware. BaseInstance and ExpressInstance. and BaseInstance.useMiddleware(middleware: BaseMiddleware) only BaseMiddleware and ExpressInstance.useMiddleware(middleware: ExpressMiddleware) but it should also accept BaseMiddleware or ExpressMiddleware. Is this impossible?

You'll need to rewrite your logic to respect LSP, either by including generic types as described in my original answer OR by making sure that functions in your derived classes don't do anything their base classes cannot do (like in your example the base class cannot access a field that only exists in the derived class).

Thanks, I'll think again about this. I will probably use custom type to match it with extends check because I need it to be like that and I can't think a way to make that respect it.

The variable x2 is of type X2 which extends X1. When you invoke func the type is changed to X1. For type X1 the only known index method is the one that accepts a F1 parameter, so it is valid, even though the inherited class "changed" type type. Changing the type of an overridden method is often considered a bad practice for this very reason.
To get the requested type safety you'd want to add generics.
If you make X1 generic you can limit it to a specific type for each extending class. An example of this looks like this:
abstract class X1<TIndex extends F1> {
    abstract index(param: TIndex);
}

class X2 extends X1<F2> {
    override index(param: F2): void {
        
    }
}

This way you will get an error if you create an instance of X2 and provide any other value then F2 to the index method.

Still doesn't make an error https://tsplay.dev/wE07kW
